# Adjusting font size of UITableViewCell based on the device size

Tags: swift, uitableview, font-size

Have been trying to change the font size inside the `UITableViewCell` dynamically based on the device size.

Code to create a table inside a UIView (in an SKScene):

```
suitsView = UIView()
suitsView.backgroundColor = .purple
suitsView.alpha = 0
self.scene?.view?.addSubview(suitsView)

suitsTableView.register(suitsTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellSuits")
suitsTableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red: 153/255, green: 255/255, blue: 153/255, alpha: 1)
suitsTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
suitsTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
suitsTableView.reloadData()
suitsTableView.alpha = 0
suitsTableView.populateTable()
displayText() // Displays Text

suitsTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
suitsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600
suitsView.addSubview(suitsTableView)
```

This is my UITableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
    let rowIsSelected = selectedIndexPaths != nil && selectedIndexPaths!.contains(indexPath)

    let cell : SuitsTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellSuits", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SuitsTableCell
    cell.lblName.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return self.bounds.height/5
}
```

This is my UITableViewCell:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
{
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

    // Font size
    var fontSize : CGFloat = 20.0

    let marginGuide = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

    lblName = UILabel()
    lblName.textColor = UIColor.black
    lblName.font = UIFont(name:"Noteworthy-Bold", size: fontSize)

    // CONSTRAINTS
    lblName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    lblName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    lblName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    lblName.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    lblName.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
    lblName.numberOfLines = 0

    lblName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    lblName.contentScaleFactor = 0.5

    contentView.addSubview(lblName)
}
```

On iPhone 8, my table looks like this:

[image]

But on iPad, it looks like this:

[image]

I need to have a bigger font in iPad. How can I adjust the font size based on constraints or the row height?

Thanks.

Edit: I am not using Storyboard; please do not suggest it.

Interestingly, if I have this code inside my cellForRow method:

```
cell.lblName.font = UIFont(name:"Noteworthy-Bold", size: (tableView.bounds.height/14).rounded())
```

I can adjust the font size but the first row (None) is always empty...

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
 // Screen width.
    public var screenWidth: CGFloat {
         return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }
 // Screen height.
    public var screenHeight: CGFloat {
         return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
    let rowIsSelected = selectedIndexPaths != nil && selectedIndexPaths!.contains(indexPath)

    let cell : SuitsTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellSuits", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SuitsTableCell
    cell.lblName.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblName.font = UIFont(name:"Noteworthy-Bold", size: (screenwidth * 0.0373).rounded()) // 0.0373 = requiredfontsize / 375
    return cell
}
```

Note: I don't know whether this method is right or wrong but I have tried this  and it worked for me.

You can go through this  for more info: [Scale text label by screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308941/scale-text-label-by-screen-size)

Answer (score 0):

Use Size-Class and hit on + symbol just before the Font tab (in storyboard) and choose Regular * Regular and set the font size as per your wish.