# View displaying partially offscreen in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

I'm building a simple iOS app while following along with an intro course on Udacity, but have run into an issue that I can't figure out how to resolve.

When running the app, my view is shifted up and off screen (this is the iPhone 6 simulator, but the results are the same regardless of which device simulator I try running it on):
[image]

What I've tried so far:

- Backing out my recent changes
- Clearing derived data/caches, restart computer
- Clean/rebuild project
- Different simulator devices
- "Reset Content and Settings" in the simulator
- Clearing constraints
- Reset to suggested constraints
- Manually deleting constraints and resetting to suggested
- Manually applying my own new constraints
- Tried to add side constraints to view, but unable to

This is my storyboard.  This scene is the "Record" scene in the center:
[image]

What could be causing it to behave like this?

Comment: Editor reset suggested constraints

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html

Comment: I have already tried that, and I also mentioned above that I've played with different values.  I don't see any change.  The thing is, I hadn't made any changes to the view itself prior to this happening.  The same constraints had worked previously.

Comment: Delete all constraints manually and reset it to suggested contraints

Comment: Tried it already.  No difference.

Comment: take a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27220627/2303865

Comment: That doesn't quite seem relevant. I'm simply using the default UIView, which doesn't allow me to add margin constraints.  I tried changing the mode on the view as shown there, but it didn't change anything either.

Comment: mode is only for images. i wanted you to see how to apply the constraints to the sides

Comment: Yeah, it's not allowing me to add those side constraints to the view.

Comment: I would recreate the layout in a separate project and try to isolate the problem

Comment: I took your advice and rebuilt it in a new project, and everything is working fine.  I'm still unsure what the issue is with the original project...
I'll be deleting this question soon, since this "solution" will likely be of little use to others.