# Swift equivalent of initWithContentsOfFile using image

Tags: objective-c, image, swift, initwithcontentsoffile

In Objective C I was using this code to scale an image to my background. How can I achieve this in Swift.

```
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"This" ofType:@"png"];
image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: Have you tried Google? First result: http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/ and even a result on StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153181/how-do-you-make-a-background-image-scale-to-screen-size-in-swift

Comment: Had been able to do this with a UIView but thanks to your reference going to a UIImageView was the start of the understanding.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("This", ofType: "png")
image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Changing from a UIView to UIImageView allowed setting .ScaleToFill.