# Align an image horizontally and vertically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation

[image]

I want to align an image in another (horizontally and vertically) to create an animation. The animation is simple: the heart will "vibrate" inside the Angry Bedou's logo, but he must be "centered" in that image.

I was trying the following:

```
    func animate() {
    heartImg.frame = CGRectMake(angryBedousImg.frame.size.width / 2, angryBedousImg.frame.size.height / 2, heartImg.frame.size.width, heartImg.frame.size.height)

    let heartAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    heartAnimation.duration = 0.09
    heartAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
    heartAnimation.autoreverses = true
    heartAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(heartImg.center.x - 1, heartImg.center.y))
    heartAnimation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(heartImg.center.x + 1, heartImg.center.y))
    heartImg.layer.addAnimation(heartAnimation, forKey: "position")
        }
```

But it wont centralizes when i build the app. The animation works, but not the alignment. I want the alignment work in every device in portrait mode.

[image]

I look at the storyboard, and the images are fine. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: via storyboard? i done that.

Comment: i don't know how to do that =/

Comment: i'm sorry @LeoDabus, but i don't understand the solution you are given

Comment: i know how to do the animation. What i don't know how to do, it's to fit the heart in the center of the imagem "angry bedou's" the works in every device. In fact, it wont work in any device test.

Comment: Break down your question first on how to position it at the other images center

Comment: just move its origin half width and half height

Comment: can you post the area of the code that you are talking about here? i continue to don't understand what you are proposing =/

Comment: I will post an example on how to position a small image in the center of a larger one. I hope it helps you positioning it

Comment: you can also instead of specifying a fixed size for your small image you can calculate it based on a percentage of the size of your screen

Comment: have u thought about adding vertical constraint inside parent view

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

This will make your heartImage centre to the background Image.

```
    let yourImage = UIImage(named: "YourImageName")
    let heartImg = UIImageView()
    heartImg.image = yourImage
    heartImg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(heartImg)
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: heartImg, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.yourLogoImage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: heartImg, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.yourLogoImage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: heartImg, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: heartImg, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your screen midX and midY properties and subtract the image's half width and half height:

```
if let imageURL = NSURL(string:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg"), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL), image = UIImage(data: data), image2URL = NSURL(string:"https://graph.facebook.com/10203430834250391/picture?type=large"), data2 = NSData(contentsOfURL: image2URL), image2 = UIImage(data: data2) {

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

    let image2View = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.midX-100, y: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.midY-100, width: 200, height: 200))
    image2View.image = image2
    image2View.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
    imageView.addSubview(image2View)
    imageView
}
```

If your image it is not the same size of your device screen you have to use the larger image frame midX minus the smaller image frame midX and do the same for the height:

```
 heartImg.frame = CGRectMake(angryBedousImg.frame.size.width / 2, angryBedousImg.frame.size.height / 2, heartImg.frame.size.width, heartImg.frame.size.height)
```

To

```
heartImg.frame = CGRectMake(angryBedousImg.frame.midX - heartImg.frame.midX, angryBedousImg.frame.midY - heartImg.frame.midY, heartImg.frame.size.width, heartImg.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: It didn't work. The heart image don't center in the angry bedou's image. =/

Comment: @ZéMoreira I can't guess what you are doing wrong you need to show  your code. forget about animating it now

Comment: What have i done wrong in the code that i posted first in this topic? I think this is the best answer i can get

Comment: thats not how SO works. I won't do your whole homework. Ask one question at a time. You don't even know how to position your Image in the center and you are already asking how to animate it

Comment: I'm not asking how to animate it, i already done that. In the code you can see it. My doubt is: Why the heart image don't align in the Angry image. I want to know what i did wrong in my code, because for me, it's all right. I take the heart position and make it: "heartImg.frame = CGRect(x: angryBedousImg.frame.size.width / 2, y: angryBedousImg.frame.size.height / 2, width: heartImg.frame.size.width, height: heartImg.frame.size.height)
" But i don't know why, it dont align. It keeps getting a little over the center of the image

Comment: It is clear if you look at my answer the difference. Position it at the screen midX minus half width and midY - half height

Comment: i don't understand you answer. that's the problem. I'm new in Swift, i don't get the download data from the web for the example.

Comment: You can copy paste my code in a playground and use it with any two images

Comment: If your view it is not the same size of the screen, use the large image frame instead of the screen bounds

Comment: it worked in the y axis, but not in the x axis. in the x axis, i still have different positions for different devices. Another thing: when i input the UIViewContentMode.Center in the heartImg, the img expands in the run time, and take almost the entire screen

Comment: I don't think that the device would be a problem

Comment: @ZéMoreira check my last edit. You were using the wrong image frame.

Comment: Ow man, it didn't work. I was using the protocol instead. The heart keep going away from the center of the angry image.

Comment: I find this solution using protocol: 

 func animate() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.09, delay:0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse], animations: {
            
            self.heartImg.center.x = self.heartImg.center.x - 1
            
            }) { (completed) -> Void in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.09, delay: 0, options: .Repeat, animations: { () -> Void in
                    
                    self.heartImg.center.x = self.heartImg.center.x + 1
                    }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

But i don't like. I prefer using CABasicAnimation

Comment: i think the problem is in the constraints. i'm searching for a solution in that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153181/how-do-you-make-a-background-image-scale-to-screen-size-in-swift/27220627#27220627

Comment: i manage to make the heart image works right in the y axis in every device:
heartImg.frame.origin.y = angryBedousImg.bounds.midY + heartImg.bounds.height / 2

But i can't find a solution to make the x axis works

Comment: Create a new project with those 2 images I can fix it for you