# Autolayouts not working as expected in iPhone 6s Plus

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have

1. UIImageviewUIView - The Background image
2. UIView - being treated as a gradient layer on top of the image.

Here the constraints given for the gradient view is

- Align top and leading to the UIImageView
- Equal height and Width as
  the UIImageView

These are working perfectly on iPhone 5s, 6s but fails to work on iPhone 6s Plus. The gradient view doesnt cover the UIImageView fully. 
Attaching a sample image

[image]

**P.S I already unchecked Constraint to margin in Interface Builder. Still not working. 
Can anyone help me with what i am missing?**

Comment: On the image view, tick the box that says "Clips to bounds"

Comment: Clip To bounds is ticked, already

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153181/how-do-you-make-a-background-image-scale-to-screen-size-in-swift/41581146#41581146) might be useful to your case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loads of trial and error. 
I finally found the solution.

- Removed Equal height and Width as the UIImageView
- Align bottom and trailing to the UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

Try these constraints on imageView and the other view on top of it:

[image]